# Bindings with Eclipse Sisu for Maven Plugin do not work for Java 17

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, java-17, plexus, eclipse-sisu

#### Reproducible at: [GitHub](https://github.com/Nikolas-Charalambidis/stackoverflow-issue-77894103)

I have a simple setup of a custom Maven plugin execution where I use `PlexusContainer` to perform a lookup for the defined containers.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

...

@Mojo(
    name = "process-sources",
    defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_SOURCES,
    instantiationStrategy = InstantiationStrategy.PER_LOOKUP,
    threadSafe = true
)
public class ProcessSourcesMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Inject
    private PlexusContainer container;

    @Parameter
    private String componentName;

    ...

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        if (container.hasComponent(MyComponent.class, componentName)) {
            try {
                final AbstractComponent myComponent = container.lookup(AbstractComponent.class, componentName);
                // USE THE COMPONENT
            } catch (ComponentLookupException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to `@Inject` a particular one but rather resolve by type and name. The components are properly defined, for example:

```java
@Named("myComponent")
public class MyComponent extends AbstractComponent {
}
```

**Problem:**

The whole problem lies in the used Java version as the newer Java versions cannot register the components properly.

- **Java 8**: `container.hasComponent(MyComponent.class, "myComponent")` -> `true`
- **Java 17**: `container.hasComponent(MyComponent.class, "myComponent")` -> `false`

**Background:**

I discovered that `maven-plugin-plugin` is responsible for generating descriptors picked up during the components scan. I have the following configuration:

```java
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>descriptor-help</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>helpmojo</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I also use Eclipse Sisu plugin as suggested:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.sisu</groupId>
    <artifactId>sisu-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

**Dependencies**

The minimum supported Maven version is `3.5.4`.

- `org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:3.5.4:compile`
- `org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:3.5.4:compile`
- `org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.5.4:compile`
- `org.apache.maven:maven-model:3.5.4:provided`
- `org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.5.4:provided`
- `org.apache.maven:maven-settings:3.5.4:provided`

---

- `org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:3.6.1:provided`

---

- `org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:4.0.0:compile`
- `org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-xml:3.0.0:compile`
- `org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:2.5.2:provided`

---

- `org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:0.9.0:M2:provided`

---

- `javax.inject:javax.inject:1:provided`
- `javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2:provided`

I tried to update the versions up and down, but no luck with running on Java 17. What is the correct combination? Is Java 17 even supported?

Comment: Please show the full pom file best would be a link to the project...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have created a reproducible version and uploaded to GitHub: https://github.com/Nikolas-Charalambidis/stackoverflow-issue-77894103

Comment: That page produces a 404!

Comment: @khmarbaise My apologies. I’ve mistakenly made the repo private. It should be visible now.

Comment: First why are you trying to support such an ancient version of Maven 3.5.4? Second the itf framework requires at minimum 3.8.4 (technically it should work with older versions) also I don't understand your test setup which uses `@MavenProject` and `@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class )` which both do not make sense here...and why already defined a nested class? And also using lombok which is not used anywhere... Or is this only related to the extracted example? Furthermore you should define `@MavenOption(MavenCLIOptions.BATCH_MODE)` because that's not automatically set...

Comment: Also why using `[WARNING]  Parameter 'systemProperties' is deprecated: Use systemPropertyVariables instead.` check the documentation of maven-failsafe-plugin or docs also already state in the itf readme: https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-it-extension/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @khmarbaise The project is not 1:1 but only a bare minimum from the real one. The nested class was copied, and there are many tests. Remember the project shared is just for the sake of this issue, don't make it perfect, though thank you for a note about the Maven versions. I am aware of other flaws. The problem I am dealing with is how to run it on Java 17. Let's, please, focus on that.

Comment: I've tested it by using BATCH_MODE on JDK8, 11, 17,21 and even 22 no issues... the problem is related in your IT... and also with different maven version 3.5.4, 3.9.6..also with Maven 4.0.0-alpha-12...

Comment: Created a PR to show some improvements. Also I would ask why using the plexusContainer? Just let the components being injected... see my PR. Also check the content of `-mvn-arguments.log` within the IT...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, updating to Maven 3.9.6 resolved my issue. Thank you for the help. If you mind creating an answer, I'd happily accept it. Also, what is a proper replacement of `PlexusContainer` for a bean lookup by name or type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to compile Maven plugin for JDK 17+ you must use a Maven 3.9.6+ for executing.

Related to issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7913

Comment: Correct. I have compiled it with Maven 3.9.6 and Java 17 and the bean lookup started to work. I am surprised Sisu is silent about the fact it skips the components of Java 14 and higher according to the link. I guess I was not able to address the problem correctly as Plexus, Sisu, Guice, and Maven internals are new to me. Thank you!